# `Configure` in Qt 5.0.1 is not recognized

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, mingw, qt5

I've downloaded Qt 5.0.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW) and want to configure it again to support OpenSSL, but I can't find `confiure.exe`.

By the way, when I use Qt 5.0.1 command prompt to use `configure`, it says "`configure.exe` is not recognized".

Comment: `confiure.exe` in your question is a typo only in this question or also in the command prompt?

Answer (score 3):

configure.exe is part of the Qt's source code - so make sure you installed that.

But anyway i recommend you download the source code from [here](https://qt-project.org/downloads) and start in a separate folder if you want to build Qt yourself (if you download the source make sure that you get the .zip from downloads, tar.gz is for linux use and doesn't have the Windows configure.exe)

Comment: Here is the source -  http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.1/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1.zip It does not seem to have configure.exe

Comment: @Mathai sure it does, it's in the _qtbase_ folder.