# QT 5.3 Location of Configure Command

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to compile QT statically.
However I am unable to run the configure command as I get the following.
'configure' is not recognized as an internal or external program.

I assume this is because I am looking in the wrong location for it.
I have tried using the windows command prompt and the one included with QT.

I've tried following the instructions in this post with no luck.

[Where can I found QT 5.3.0 command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219732/where-can-i-found-qt-5-3-0-command-prompt)

Comment: did you start that bat file from your cmd prompt?

Comment: I started the qtenv2.bat and get a message "Setting up environment for Qt Usage..." 
But it doesn't help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`Configure\` in Qt 5.0.1 is not recognized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796518/configure-in-qt-5-0-1-is-not-recognized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your command prompt, you need to cd the location where your configure.exe executable is. You should be able to search for it in the search bar of your root qt directory. For my build, it is located under C:\Qt\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1\qtbase\configure.exe

Comment: I've tried searching my entire Qt directory for this the best I find is a configure.prf file under mkspec. Could there be a problem with my install?

Comment: which QT are you using?

Comment: I am using QT 5.3
I am reinstalling right now to see if it solves the issue.

Comment: No luck with the reinstall

Comment: If you're using the installers, those just install the libraries that are pre-compiled from your OS/compiler. To build the libraries from scratch you'll need to download the source.